# CSS line wrapping

Tags: css

Given a block container

```
<div>
 this is a very long string which contains a bunch of characters that I want to break at container edges.
</div>
```

are there any css properties I can set to force it to break when it reaches the container width, regardless of the contents of the string, for example a break like:

```
this is a ve
ry long stri
ng which ...
```

is pretty much what I want. Right now, it seems to always prefer to break at whitespace characters or other special characters (such as /).

Comment: You can maybe ask the same question over at http://doctype.com/questions :)

Comment: StackOverflow is still sufficient for these kind of questions.

Comment: @Magnus: No offense, but I haven't found doctype to be a very good source of answers for questions that shade toward the technical.

Comment: @Robusto: None taken. I thought I were giving good advice. Glad to have that sorted out :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a CSS3 property called `word-break` that may be of some use to you in future.

More information is available here: http://www.css3.com/css-word-break/

The `break-all` value looks to do the thing you're asking for:

> Useful where content contains a majority of Asian character set content, to which this value behaves like ‘normal’. Non-Asian character set content may be arbitrarily broken across lines.

As for more supported versions of CSS, I don't believe there's a way you can do this.

Comment: Thank you, the CSS3 property "word-break: break-all;" worked in Webkit, but sadly it doesn't work (or is hidden somewhere else) in firefox. One browser done, a few to go :).

Comment: Accepted, since you solved it for a few browsers. It doesn't seem possible to solve with CSS for Firefox yet :(

Comment: This works in the majority of browsers now. See http://caniuse.com/#search=word-break

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
<style type="text/css">
div {
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, supported since 1999 */
white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4 - 6 */
white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
white-space: pre-wrap; /* CSS3 - Text module (Candidate Recommendation) http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#white-space */
word-wrap: break-word; /* IE 5.5+ */
}
</style>

<div style="width:200px">
adsjflk;asjfl;kasdjfl;kasdjfl;kasdjf;lkasdjf;lkasdjf;lkasjdf;lkajsd;lkadfjs;l
</div>
```

Comment: Almost, sadly it still prefers to break on hyphens and whitespace, if it can (Webkit). In Firefox it breaks on the aforementioned characters in addition to / :(.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative way achieve the same by enclosing the div in a parent div and setting the width of the parent div. Though it might not be the ideal solution.

```
<div style="width:50px">
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Sadly it seems most browsers still prefer to break on whitespace if the following word doesn't fit on the current line :/.