# Checkbox in a table withouth start a new line automatically

Tags: html, line-breaks, word-wrap

I have this part of code:

```
<td>

    <label class="radio inline" onclick="document.forms['form_user_{{ user.id }}'].submit();">
    <input type="radio" name="perms" id="perms_{{user.id}}_0" user_id="{{user.id}}" value="0">
    None
    </label>
    <label class="radio inline" onclick="document.forms['form_user_{{ user.id }}'].submit();">
    <input type="radio" name="perms" id="perms_{{user.id}}_1" user_id="{{user.id}}" value="1">
    Read
    </label>
    <label class="radio inline" onclick="document.forms['form_user_{{ user.id }}'].submit();">
    <input type="radio" name="perms" id="perms_{{user.id}}_4" user_id="{{user.id}}" value="4">
    Read + Commands
    </label>
    </td>
```

But when I open the page the result is this:

[image: html page]

I don't know why the line Read + Commands break the line...

There's a way to manually manage the wrap of the line?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738367/css-line-wrapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the CSS property white-space:

```
table td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

But I am not sure how it will apply under a label inside the td

Comment: And if I write `style=”word-break: keep-all”`in the label element?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to apply a style on `<td>` element and set appropriate width.

```
    <td style="width: 400px;">
OR
    <td class="myStyleTD">

    .myStyleTD
    {
    width: 50%;
    }
```