# Sphinx field list - url line break formatting

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm using sphinx to generate the documentation for a project.

I'm using field list, referencing a long url.

My reST script is below:

```
**Operação**
^^^^^^^^^^^^

:Fonte: https://google.com.br
:Github: https://github.com/123456789876543221/hello_world/987654321/random/path/lalalalalalallaa/12345678987654321.py
:Tópicos adicionais: lorem ipsum.
:Pós-processamento: \-
```

The generated html is:

[image]

How can I split the URL in two lines, in order not to strangle the left column with field categories?

Comment: Try custom CSS for your theme and this technique. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738367/css-line-wrapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Costumizing the CSS seems the right way to go. But if you want an "quick fix" using only **reST** directives the most pratical would seem:

1. [Truncating the URL](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#embedded-uris-and-aliases). (Drawback of selectivly shortening the URL.)
2. Using a costum [List Table](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#list-table). (Drawback of changing the field list format.)

[image]

```
**Operacao**
^^^^^^^^^^^^

:Fonte: `a short url`_
:Github: alongurl_
:Tópicos: `https://www.a_very_long_url/..truncated../file.html`_ lorem ipsum.


.. _a short url: http://google.com
.. _alongurl: http://google.com/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
.. _https://www.a_very_long_url/..truncated../file.html: https://github.com/123456789876543221/hello_world/987654321/random/path/lalalalalalallaa/12345678987654321.py


.. list-table:: 
   :widths: 30

   * - :Fonte: alongurl_ 
   * - :Github: If we took the bones out, it wouldn't be crunchy, now would it?jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj 
   * - :Tópicos: https://github.com/123456789876543221/hello_world/987654321/random/path/lalalalalalallaa/12345678987654321.py
```

I thought about editing or substituting the [Hyperlinks References](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#hyperlink-references) using [Substitution Definitions](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#substitution-definitions) but apparently **reST** doesn't allow that.

You could [define the HTML in an external file and include it](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#including-an-external-document-fragment), or use [Raw Data Pass-Through](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#raw-data-pass-through) but, in this specific case those still seem inferior "workarounds" for what should essentially be achieved using CSS.

Also, I thought of using [Line Blocks](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#line-blocks) (or similar) inside the [List Table](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#embedded-uris-and-aliases) as a way to manually separate the URL into lines. But that seems like pushing the **reST** markup syntax beyond its supposed use...

There might be a really smart way to do it, if you understand the [Element Hierarchy](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/doctree.html#element-hierarchy) well enough, but I'd keep things simple by making changes on the endproduct HTML through CSS instead of detail customizing the **reST**.